# Ensure minimal information loss with classifiears with Python's Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset with a lot of columns / features, I want to make ML model that will classify data into 1s and 0s but I want to reduce the number of columns.
I have read a lot about `feature selection` but something is not clear to me.
How can I ensure minimal information lost when I reduce the number of columns / features, or how can I know if I lost a lot of information?
Whats the optimal number of features that I can remove, how can I know that I did not overfit the model?

I have used `PCA`, and I made something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


values = [0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97]

for i in values:
    print(i)

    pca = PCA(i)

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 0)

    pca.fit(x_train)

    x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
    x_test = pca.transform(x_test)

    print(pca.n_components_)

    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    # provera tacnosti
    model_score1 = model.score(x_train, y_train)
    model_score2 = model.score(x_test, y_test)

    print(model_score1, model_score2)

    prediction_result =  model.predict(x_test)
    accuracy_test = accuracy_score(y_test, prediction_result)

    prediction_result_train =  model.predict(x_train)
    accuracy_train= accuracy_score(y_train, prediction_result_train)

    print(accuracy_train, accuracy_test)
```

I have checked `score` and `accuracy_score` of train and test data because I want to be sure that I do not have overfitting (big difference between train and test accuracy)

I have used also used 'RFE' (but It takes a lot of time), and I have also used `ExtraTreesClassifier` and `RandomForestClassifier` with `model.feature_importances_`:

```
model = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
model.fit(x, y)
extra_tree_score = model.feature_importances_   

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
model.fit(x, y)
extra_tree_score = model.feature_importances_
```

I like `model.feature_importances_` but I do not know what features should I take *(top 10, top 50, top 75) to ensure minimal information lost.

Answer (score 0):

**Feature Selection**

PCA is just a method for dimension reduction. By using PCA, your feature will change and they not have their original interpretation.

If you want to use dimension reduction especially PCA, you could test how PCA works. It's easy just by :Percentage of variance (information) for by each PC. If rotated data coordination does not keep enough data of original, so PCA does not work well. you could see good graph of PC in

[image]

[A step by step explanation of Principal Component Analysis](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-explanation-of-principal-component-analysis-b836fb9c97e2)

PCA doesn't work well for nonlinear data. So PCA is not possible always.

You could check data correlation for remove redundancy in your data.

[How to Calculate Correlation Between Variables in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-correlation-to-understand-the-relationship-between-variables/)

When two features(variables) have a good correlation with each other:
[image]

For test correlation for multiple features, its better look at this link:

[Finding Correlation Between Many Variables (Multidimensional Dataset) with Python](https://medium.com/@sebastiannorena/finding-correlation-between-many-variables-multidimensional-dataset-with-python-5deb3f39ffb3)

In this matrix confusion, you see that arrow and wind have correlation.

[image]

There are many nonlinear methods for dimension reduction. For nonlinear I found this package for python.

[pyHSICLasso](https://pypi.org/project/pyHSICLasso/)

Comment: Ok  but how to check if my data is linear if I have 100 features.
I have tried `df.corr()` and then I sorted those values by `output` to see if the values are close to 1 or -1, and I found out that most data is between -0.4 and +0.4, that means that my data is not linear?

What are methods for feature selection for non linear data?